# UITableView cell displays "null" value in index 0

Tags: iphone, uitableview, null, indexing, nsuserdefaults

I have textview in VC. Saving this textview using nsuserdefaults and get it later. In VC1 im getting saved textview and displaying in UITableView. But when i launch the app it automcatically displays "null" text in index 0.

VC:

```
-(void)save:(id)sender{

   NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData1 setObject:textView.text forKey:@"savetext"];
    [userData1 synchronize];
}
```

VC1:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     // textArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    txt=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // getting an NSString
     NSString *savedValue = [prefs stringForKey:@"savetext"];

    NSLog(@"saved is %@",savedValue);

    txt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", savedValue];

    NSLog(@"text.txt is %@", txt.text);

    MyAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  if(![MyAppDelegate.textArray containsObject:txt.text]){
        [MyAppDelegate.textArray addObject:txt.text];
    }

   NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData1 setObject:MyAppDelegate.textArray forKey:@"save"];
    [userData1 synchronize];

}
```

UITableView displays the text values using array:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSMutableArray* myMutableArrayAgain = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"]];

     NSLog(@"array is %@",myMutableArrayAgain);

     return [myMutableArrayAgain count];

  }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableArray* myMutableArrayAgain = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"]];

    NSLog(@"mycell is %@",myMutableArrayAgain);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"cell is %@",cell);

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        NSLog(@"cell inside is %@",cell);

    }

 // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [myMutableArrayAgain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}
```

[image]

Comment: What object returns from `[myMutableArrayAgain objectAtIndex:0]`? Is it `NSNull`?

Comment: add this as last line in `viewWillApear`, `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: @jszumski: [myMutableArrayAgain objectAtIndex:0] is NULL

Comment: @samfisher: last line also not working

Comment: when i use  [myMutableArrayAgain objectAtIndex:1]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: Does anyone help this..

Comment: NSLog(@"array is %@",myMutableArrayAgain); is it getting null array?

Comment: Im getting array is (
    "(null)"
)

Comment: @karthika: can you help this...

Answer (score 0):

This is all because the code is wrong at some places:

1) Nsmutable array with array is wrong:- as the userdefaults is returning you a single string.
   So do it like this:-

```
 NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray* myMutableArrayAgain = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[userData1 valueForKey:@"savetext"]];
```

2) In VC you are saving the value for key in "savetext" but in VC1 you are retrieving the value as "save", so change it, it has been done in the above code.

// The above 2 points would solve your problem but I would say don't code like this as it would consume more memory and would remove tidyness of your code. The code which you have done can be done in a very efficient way.
I tell you .

// Take first View controller VC and add IBAction to a button and a textView or textField what ever. 
Write this code in VC :-

.h file

```
@interface demoViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txt1;
}

-(IBAction)getData:(id)sender;
```

.m file

// first include header file of the next controller where you want to redirect suppose XYZ

```
#import XYZ.h

-(IBAction)getData:(id)sender{
    NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData1 setObject:txt1.text forKey:@"savetext"];
    demoViewController1 *demo=[[demoViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"demoViewController1" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:demo animated:NO];
}
```

// Take the second controller IN taht on ViewDisLoad or ViewDidAppear whatever you feel like

// Take a global MuttableArray

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArrayAgain;
```

// I write this code on ViewDidload allocate the array here as MutableObject need to be allocated

```
 NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    myMutableArrayAgain=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [myMutableArrayAgain addObject: [userData1 valueForKey:@"savetext"]];
```

// Now table View Methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [myMutableArrayAgain count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"cell is %@",cell);

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSLog(@"cell inside is %@",cell);    
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [myMutableArrayAgain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

// Apply this way you can do the stuff in less code and in a great way.